# ¿Cómo eliminar doble, dobles comillas de un String?

Tags: c#

Tengo esta cadena en String

```
 ""texto1"": {
   ""texto"": ""17/10/2021""
```

Y necesito eliminar una de las dobles comillas que existen de forma que quede de la siguiente manera

```
 "texto1": {
        "texto2": "17/10/2021"
```

Comment: Agrega como  lo estas leyendo, es decir el codigo incluido, y tambien lo que hayas intentado, aqui se dan recomendaciones o sugerencias, para solucionarlo juntos.

Answer (score 1):

Has de indagar un poco en los métodos que posee el tipo string. Para tu caso lo que te va ayudar es el método Replace que te va a sustituir una cadena por otra.

```
string dcom = "\x022\x022"; // Cadena que contiene dos doble comilla:  ""
// En esta variable texto se recrea la cadena inicial.
string texto = dcom + "texto1" + dcom + ":{" + 
               dcom + "texto"  + dcom + ":"+
               dcom + "17/10/2021" + dcom;  
  
// Muestra el valor de la variable texto que es tu input en el problema
Console.WriteLine(texto);
// Reemplazamos las dos dobles comillas por una sola.
texto = texto.Replace(dcom, "\x022");
// Mostramos el resultado
Console.WriteLine(texto);
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar esto:

```
//cuando se detecta que un string viene con comillas en la visualizacion aparece como ("\"texto\"")
texto=texto.Replace("\"","")
//o tambien
texto=texto.Replace(@"""","")
```

Answer (score 0):

la variable **dobleComilla** es la cadena que tiene las doble comillas

```
 string dobleComilla= "\"texto1\": {\n   \"texto\": \"17/10/2021\"";
```

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es utilizar el metodo **Replace()** y agregas la comilla deseada a obtener

```
 string resultado= dobleComilla.Replace("\"texto\": \"", "\"texto2\": \"");
            Console.Write(resultado);
```

resultado final de la variable **resultado**

```
"texto1": {
   "texto2": "17/10/2021"
```